# Хранение не целых чисел mysql

Tags: mysql

В mysql записываются дробные числа. Они должны хранится в базе до точностью на n ое количество после запятой. Решил пользоваться`DECIMAL(9,2)`  , но оказывается он максимум может хранить до 9999999.99 , а мне нужно чтоб он хранил больше ? Что использовать ?

Comment: Как и везде в программировании - float, double

Comment: спасибо за ответ , но забыл сказать что это денежные данные. Всё равно float, double ?

Comment: Согласно документации https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html  decimal способен хранить до 65 десятичных знаков. просто увеличьте разрядность при объявлении типа. хоть до `decimal(65,2)`

Comment: @ArcherGodson На стаковерфлоу матерится не принято. А что касается 9 знаков для денег - то это очень мало. кто же говорит что там рубли. у некоторых валют курс к по миллиону за 1 рубль

Comment: Полностю с Вами согласен !

Comment: В дополнение можно отметить, что первое число у decimal обозначает общее число знаков, а второе - число знаков после запятой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так можно же использовать, например `DECIMAL(13,2)`. Из [справки](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html), как подсказал [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike):

```
Синтаксис объявления для поля типа DECIMAL такой: 
  DECIMAL (M, D)

Диапазоны значений для аргументов следующие:
  M - максимальное количество цифр (точность). Он имеет диапазон от 1 до 65.
  D - количество цифр справа от десятичной точки (масштаб). Он имеет диапазон от 0 до 30 и должен быть не больше M.
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ так и поступил